# Close a non-button flyout?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a Flyout attached to the LayoutRoot grid.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Key="WinningPopup">
        <StackPanel Margin="50,10">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="Flyout_VictoryTitle" 
                               Text="Victory!" 
                               Style="{StaticResource MessageDialogTitleStyle}" 
                               Margin="0,0,0,15"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Flyout_VictoryDescription"
                               x:Uid="Flyout_VictoryDescription" 
                               Text="Congratulations!&#x0a;Score: " 
                               Style="{StaticResource MessageDialogContentStyle}" />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="btnRestart" 
                                x:Uid="btnRestart"
                                Click="btnRestart_Click"
                                Content="[Restart]" 
                                Margin="10"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnCancel" 
                                x:Uid="btnCancel"
                                Click="btnCancel_Click" 
                                Content="[Cancel]" 
                                Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource WinningPopup}">
...
```

I open this Flyout with

```
FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(LayoutRoot);
```

But how to close it? I know the user can tap outside, but I also need to close the flyout when you click the restart o the cancel button...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give it a Name

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Name="myFlyout" x:Key="WinningPopup">
        // ......
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then you can just Hide()

```
myFlyout.Hide();
```

[FlyoutBase.Hide method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.hide.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void btnRestart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs) 
{
    ((((sender as Button).Parent as StackPanel).Parent as StackPanel).Parent as Flyout).Hide();
}
```

Very ugly but should work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get it first. Then you can call `Hide`.

```
FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)LayoutRoot).Hide();
```